# WPF Trigger CollectionViewSource Refresh From Another Property Changes

Tags: c#, wpf

I have a CollectionViewSource that binds to a custom ObservableDictionary which is in the format of:

```cs
ObservableDictionary<int, List<Waypoint>>
```

A waypoint instance is in a format of:

```cs
public class Waypoint
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public float X { get; set; }
    public float Y { get; set; }
    public float Z { get; set; }
}
```

Within the same view model, I have another property 'MapId' that is updated as the player moves between maps. I am trying to bind this ObservableDictionary  instance to a  ListBox to show only the waymaps of a give map based on its mapid. (The int of the dictionary is the map id.)

Is there a way to cause a CollectionViewSource to force-refresh based on another property binding being updated?

I am trying to do this mostly in XAML with as little code-behind as possible.

Here is some of what I have for this currently.

In my view:

```
<CollectionViewSource x:Key="WaypointCollection" Filter="WaypointCollection_OnFilter" Source="{Binding Waypoints, Source={StaticResource Configurations}}" 
                      />
```

In my view code-behind (filter):

```
    private void WaypointCollection_OnFilter(object sender, FilterEventArgs e)
    {
        var main = SimpleIoc.Default.GetInstance<MainViewModel>();
        if (main == null)
        {
            e.Accepted = false;
            return;
        }

        var waypoint = (KeyValuePair<int, List<Waypoint>>)e.Item;
        var zone = main.Player.ZoneId;
        e.Accepted = waypoint.Key == zone;
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I resorted to creating a service to handle loading things as needed via async tasks. Works as needed although it is not the approach I originally wanted.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot bind. Because they are not `DependencyObject`(DO). But if this `another property` is a DO/DP. Then you can force refresh using [Refresh](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.data.collectionview.refresh%28v=vs.110%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) method. You can specify a callback to get notified of any changes to this DP, while registering your DP.

```
... , new PropertyMetadata(new PropertyChangedCallback(MyCallback));
```